# Как найти младший бит заданого числа?

Tags: python

Для заданого положительного целого A (1 ≤ A ≤ 100), вывести младший бит A.
*К примеру, если A = 26, то его мы можем записать в двоичном виде, как 11010,
младший бит A составляет 10, и на выходе должно быть 2.Другой пример выглядит следующим образом: при A = 88, это число A мы можем записать в
двоичной форме 1011000, младший бит у A является 1000, и на выходе должно быть 8.*

**Входные данные**
Каждая строка входных данных содержит только одно целое число A (1 ≤ A ≤ 100).  Строка, которая
содержащий "0" обозначает конец ввода, и эта строка не является частью входных данных.
**Исходные данные:**
для каждого числа a, полученного на входе, в отдельной строке вывести его значение
младшего бита.
***Нужно написать на Python***

Comment: фигасе тут интересный «младший бит», который равен то `10`, то `1000`. это на каком же языке? на русском математическом ведь полный бред получается.

Comment: Все правильно сказано в вопросе ж. На обычном математическом

Comment: @Grandmother -  вы опять какой-то бред несете.  Ну хоть в Википедию загляните, прежде чем писать то, в чем вы не разбираетесь: "1 бит информации — символ или сигнал, который может принимать два значения: включено или выключено, да или нет, высокий или низкий, заряженный или незаряженный; в двоичной системе исчисления это 1 (единица) или 0 (ноль). "

Answer (score 2):

можно проверять делимость на степени двойки

```
A = 88
t = 2
while not A % t:
    t *= 2

print(t//2) # 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Младший бит числа можно найти, преобразовав его в двоичный вид и находя первый "1" в справа. Мы можем преобразовать число в двоичный вид с помощью встроенной функции bin в Python.

```
def find_least_significant_bit(a):
    binary = bin(a)
    least_significant_bit = binary.rfind("1") + 1
    return 2**(len(binary) - least_significant_bit)
```

Чтобы использовать эту функцию, нам нужно читать числа, пока они не равны 0, и вызывать find_least_significant_bit для каждого из них:

```
while True:
    a = int(input().strip())
    if a == 0:
        break
    print(find_least_significant_bit(a))
```

PS. Надеюсь хоть не много помог)

Comment: Норм разложил :) Ток вот для тех кто такие задачи просит сильно загнул, не поверят их препады что они сами сделали XD

Comment: вдруг человек, не разработчик... только исходя из этого выложил свою версию)

Answer (score 0):

Ммм.... Я все же останусь в касте истинно верующих в то, что "младший бит" любого числа это всегда последний разряд в двоичном представлении и он получается просто как результат остатка от деления на 2

```
A = 88
bit = A % 2
print(f"Младший бит числа {A} равен {bit}\n")
```

Выведет:

```
Младший бит числа 88 равен 0
```

Но если вдруг все же вам надо найти первый значимый (равный единице) бит справа и вернуть полученное таким образом число, то... Вообще-то можно представить число в двоичной форме, преобразовать в строку, разбить на подстроки по разделителю "1". Длина последнего элемента массива будет искомой степенью двойки )))

Такой вот забавный код

```
A = 88
Anew = str(bin(A))
print(f"{A} в двоичной записи равно {Anew}")
Anew = Anew.split('1')
degree = len(Anew[-1])
print(f"Наименьшее значимое справа будет 1{Anew[-1]}")
res = 2**degree
print(f"2 в степени {degree} будет {res}\n")
```

Выведет:

```
88 в двоичной записи равно 0b1011000
Наименьшее значимое справа будет 1000
2 в степени 3 будет 8
```